# Issues retrieving Branch deep link parameters in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, branch.io

I'm having trouble with this line:

```
let isBranchLinkKey = "+clicked_branch_link"
guard let didClickBranchLink = params[isBranchLinkKey] as? Int else { return }
```

`didClickBranchLink` is nil even though in the debugger the parameter is there.

Below is a screenshot of my debugger:

[image].

[image: second screenshot]

Comment: print `param` and also check if `didClickBranchLink` can be converted to int.

Comment: didClickBranchLink will be either a 0 or a 1 according to Branch.io documentation and which i've confirmed.

Comment: try `po params[isBranchLinkKey]` in console and see what it prints.

Comment: I thought it might be a casting issue as params is originally a [AnyHashable: Any] that I cast to a [String: AnyObject], but, I tried that out in a playground and it worked.

Comment: Actually if you look at the debugger screenshot you can see what it prints out already

Comment: I meant try `po params[isBranchLinkKey]!`. Notice the `!` at the end. See what it prints. Sorry earlier I missed that.

Comment: @adev hey that actually will print a 1 or 0

Comment: Can you please add that screenshot to question? May be we can look at it and see why it is not 1 or 0.

Comment: @adev added the screenshot.

Comment: From your screenshot it seems like `paramBranchLink` is of type `Bool`. And you are trying to cast it as `Int` which fails. So it makes sense. So you should try to get it as `Bool` itself in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the edited screenshot, `paramBranchLink` is of a `boolean` value(Notice `__NSCFBoolean` in debugger on left side) but you are trying to cast as `Int` in guard statement. Since in swift both are two different types, the guard statement will fail. You should change your guard statement to get it as `Bool` value.

```
guard let didClickBranchLink = params[isBranchLinkKey] as? Bool else { return }
```

This should give a `boolean` value in `didClickBranchLink` which you can use it in your later part of the code.

Comment: Hey this worked.  It was also helpful that you made me realize the params[isBranchLinkKey] is actually an optional.  The guard statement didn't work as i wanted if both the cast and the params[isBranchLinkKey] were optionals that could be nil.